# Extracting unstructured table from PDF file Python

Tags: python, tabula

I have been trying to extract tables from a PDF. These tables are really unstructured meaning they run onto multiple pages, elements that should be in a single cell run into multiple cells (the rows below). I have been using tabula on python. I first tried converting all the tables in the pdf into csv by doing this

```
tabula.convert_into("../Data/Turi.pdf","../Data/Turi.csv", pages = 'all')
```

and it was a complete mess of a csv file.
So then I tried extracting tables separately and

```
# Read PDF File
DF2 = tabula.read_pdf(PDF_path,pages='8', stream = True, guess = True)
# DF2 is a list of one dataframe (I extracted the dataframe from the list)
Monoterpenes_1 = (DF2[0])
# Drop all columns not containing chemical names
Monoterpenes_1.drop(Monoterpenes_1.columns.difference(['Chrysanthemol']), 1, inplace=True)
# Move chemical name from column name
Monoterpenes_1 = Monoterpenes_1.append({'Chrysanthemol':Monoterpenes_1}, ignore_index=True)
# Change column name 
Monoterpenes_1.columns =['Monoterpenes']

# Read PDF File
DF3 = tabula.read_pdf(PDF_path,pages='9', stream = True, guess = True)
# DF2 is a list of one dataframe (I extracted the dataframe from the list)
Monoterpenes_2 = (DF3[0])
# Drop all columns not containing chemical names
Monoterpenes_2.drop(Monoterpenes_2.columns.difference(['Gamma-terpinene']), 1, inplace=True)
# Move chemical name from column name
Monoterpenes_2 = Monoterpenes_2.append({'Gamma-terpinene':Monoterpenes_2}, ignore_index=True)
# Change column name 
Monoterpenes_2.columns =['Monoterpenes']
```

then concatenate into one table

```
frames = [Monoterpenes_1, Monoterpenes_2]
Monoterpenes = pd.concat(frames)
```

but I am still having the same problem of having info that is supposed to be in a single cell extending to two or three cells.
Is there any way to fix this on python or do I need to go in and fix the issues by hand?
Thank You!

```
# Read PDF File
DF2 = tabula.read_pdf(PDF_path,pages='8', stream = True, guess = True)
# DF2 is a list of one dataframe (I extracted the dataframe from the list)
Monoterpenes_1 = (DF2[0])
# Drop all columns not containing chemical names
Monoterpenes_1.drop(Monoterpenes_1.columns.difference(['Chrysanthemol']), 1, inplace=True)
# Move chemical name from column name
Monoterpenes_1 = Monoterpenes_1.append({'Chrysanthemol':Monoterpenes_1}, ignore_index=True)
# Change column name 
Monoterpenes_1.columns =['Monoterpenes']

# Read PDF File
DF3 = tabula.read_pdf(PDF_path,pages='9', stream = True, guess = True)
# DF2 is a list of one dataframe (I extracted the dataframe from the list)
Monoterpenes_2 = (DF3[0])
# Drop all columns not containing chemical names
Monoterpenes_2.drop(Monoterpenes_2.columns.difference(['Gamma-terpinene']), 1, inplace=True)
# Move chemical name from column name
Monoterpenes_2 = Monoterpenes_2.append({'Gamma-terpinene':Monoterpenes_2}, ignore_index=True)
# Change column name 
Monoterpenes_2.columns =['Monoterpenes']
```

then concatenate into one table

```
frames = [Monoterpenes_1, Monoterpenes_2]
Monoterpenes = pd.concat(frames)
```

I wanted a clean csv file

Comment: How did you get on with this in the end?